# How to plot line graph of normalized differences from binned data with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have several sets of data that I calculate binned normalized differences for. The results I want to plot within a single line plot using ggplot.  The lines representing different combinations of the paired differences are supposed to be distinguished by colors and line types.

I am stuck on taking the computed values from the bins (would be y-axis values now), and plotting these onto an x-axis.

Below is the code I use for importing the data and calculating the normalized differences.

```
# Read data from column 3 as data table for different number of rows
# you could use replicate here for test
# dat1 <- data.frame(replicate(1,sample(25:50,10000,rep=TRUE)))
# dat2 <- data.frame(replicate(1,sample(25:50,9500,rep=TRUE)))
dat1 <- fread("/dir01/a/dat01.txt", header = FALSE, data.table=FALSE, select=c(3))
dat2 <- fread("/dir02/c/dat02.txt", header = FALSE, data.table=FALSE, select=c(3))

# Change column names
colnames(dat1) <- c("Dat1")
colnames(dat2) <- c("Dat2")

# Perhaps there is a better way to compute the following as all-in-one? I have broken these down step by step.
# 1) Sum for each bin
bin1 = cut(dat1$Dat1, breaks = seq(25, 50, by = 2))
sum1 = tapply(dat1$Dat1, bin1, sum)

bin2 = cut(dat2$Dat2, breaks = seq(25, 50, by = 2))
sum2 = tapply(dat2$Dat2, bin2, sum)

# 2) Total sum of all bins
sumt1 = sum(sum1)
sumt2 = sum(sum2)

# 3) Divide each bin by total sum of all bins
sumn1 = lapply(sum1, `/`, sumt1)
sumn2 = lapply(sum2, `/`, sumt2)

# 4) Convert to data frame as I'm not sure how to difference otherwise
df_sumn1 = data.frame(sumn1)
df_sumn2 = data.frame(sumn2)

# 5) Difference between the two as percentage
dbin = (df_sumn1 - df_sumn2)*100
```

How can I plot those results using `ggplot()` and `geom_line()`?
I want

- `dbin` values on the x-axis ranging from 25-50
- different colors and line types for the lines

Here is what I tried:

```
p1 <- ggplot(dbin, aes(x = ?, color=Data, linetype=Data)) +
            geom_line() +
            scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid")) +
            scale_x_continuous(limits = c(25, 50)) +
            scale_color_manual(values = c("#000000"))
```

`dput(dbin)` outputs:

```
structure(list(X.25.27. = -0.0729132928804117, X.27.29. = -0.119044772581772,
    X.29.31. = 0.316016473225017, X.31.33. = -0.292812782147632,
    X.33.35. = 0.0776336591308158, X.35.37. = 0.0205584754637611,
    X.37.39. = -0.300768421159599, X.39.41. = -0.403235174844081,
    X.41.43. = 0.392510458816457, X.43.45. = 0.686758883448307,
    X.45.47. = -0.25387105113263, X.47.49. = -0.0508324553382303), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-1L))
```

#### Edit

The final piece of code that works, using only the dbin and plots multiple dbins:

```
dat1 <- data.frame(a = replicate(1,sample(25:50,10000,rep=TRUE, prob = 25:0/100)))
dat2 <- data.frame(a = replicate(1,sample(25:50,9500,rep=TRUE, prob = 0:25/100)))
dat3 <- data.frame(a = replicate(1,sample(25:50,9500,rep=TRUE, prob = 12:37/100)))
dat4 <- data.frame(a = replicate(1,sample(25:50,9500,rep=TRUE, prob = 37:12/100)))

calc_bin_props <- function(data) {
  as_tibble(data) %>%
    mutate(bin = cut(a, breaks = seq(25, 50, by = 2))) %>%
    group_by(bin) %>%
    summarise(sum = sum(a), .groups = "drop") %>%
    filter(!is.na(bin)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(sum = sum / sum(sum))
}

diff_data <-
  full_join(
    calc_bin_props(data = dat1),
    calc_bin_props(dat2),
    by = "bin") %>%
  separate(bin, c("trsh", "bin", "trshb", "trshc")) %>%
  mutate(dbinA = (sum.x - sum.y * 100)) %>%
  select(-starts_with("trsh"))

diff_data2 <-
  full_join(
    calc_bin_props(data = dat3),
    calc_bin_props(dat4),
    by = "bin") %>%
  separate(bin, c("trsh", "bin", "trshb", "trshc")) %>%
  mutate(dbinB = (sum.x - sum.y * 100)) %>%
  select(-starts_with("trsh"))

# Combine two differences, and remove sum.x and sum.y
full_data <- cbind(diff_data, diff_data2[,4])
full_data <- full_data[,-c(2:3)]

# Melt the data to plot more than 1 variable on a plot
m <- melt(full_data, id.vars="bin")

theme_update(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
ggplot(m, aes(as.numeric(bin), value, col=variable, linetype = variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid", "longdash")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "black"))
dev.off()
```

Comment: Can you please provide the data of either `dat1` and `dat2` or `dbin`. If you run `dput(dbin)` or if that object is very big instead do `dput(head(dbin))` and copy + paste the ouput of that in an additional code snippet in your question. That will allow the readers of your question to provide a tested solution for your issue.

Comment: I added the output of what a couple replicated dats have for dbin @Till

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)
```

Creating example data as shown in question, but adding different probabilities to the two `sample()` calls, to create so visible difference
between the two sets of randomized data.

```r
dat1 <- data.frame(a = replicate(1,sample(25:50,10000,rep=TRUE, prob = 25:0/100))) %>% as_tibble()
dat2 <- data.frame(a = replicate(1,sample(25:50,9500,rep=TRUE, prob = 0:25/100))) %>% as_tibble()
```

Using `dplyr` we can handle this within `data.frame`s (`tibble`s) without
the need to switch to other datatypes.

Let’s define a function that can be applied to both datasets to get
the preprocessing done.

We use `base::cut()` to create
a new column that pairs each value with its bin. We then group the data
by `bin`, calculate the sum for each bin and finally divide the bin sums
by the total sum.

```r
calc_bin_props <- function(data) {
  as_tibble(data) %>%
    mutate(bin = cut(a, breaks = seq(25, 50, by = 2), labels = seq(25, 48, by = 2))) %>%
    group_by(bin) %>%
    summarise(sum = sum(a), .groups = "drop") %>%
    filter(!is.na(bin)) %>% 
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(sum = sum / sum(sum))
}
```

Now we call `calc_bin_props()` on both datasets and join them by `bin`.
This gives us a dataframe with the columns `bin`, `sum.x` and `sum.y`.
The latter two are correspond to the bin sums derived from `dat1` and
`dat2`. With the `mutate()` line we calculate the differences between the
two columns.

```r
diff_data <- 
  full_join(
    calc_bin_props(data = dat1),
    calc_bin_props(dat2),
    by = "bin") %>% 
  mutate(dbin = (sum.x - sum.y),
         bin = as.numeric(as.character(bin))) %>% 
  select(-starts_with("trsh"))
```

Before we feed the data into `ggplot()` we convert it to the long
format using `pivot_longer()` this allows us to instruct `ggplot()` to
plot the results for `sum.x`, `sum.y` and `dbin` as separate lines.

```r
diff_data %>% 
  pivot_longer(-bin) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(as.numeric(bin), value, color = name, linetype = name)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("longdash", "solid", "solid")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "purple", "green"))
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to be incorrect and does not match my original computation. I will add this as an edit to this question momentarily.

Comment: I was mistaken about the way `dplyr::ntile()` works. Answer is now updated and produces the exact same numeric results as your original code. In regards to the plot, please specify more accurately what you are looking for in your question, possibly provide a sketch of the plot you want.

Comment: I did not multiply the dbin values by 100 though, as that leads to too highly scaled values in order to visually compare them to the bin sum values.

Comment: This works and the values compare well. Is there a way to set the x-axis between 25 and 50 in the last plot "original code" example as you did in your first plot example? This is due to the data existing between 25 and 50 (technically infinity, but I cut them off at 50). Otherwise, I suppose only plotting the dbin, however there will be many dbins computed (from multiple data comparisons) that I would like plotted on the same plot but as different color lines.

Comment: The values should be exactly the same, `tibble`'s `print()` method rounds values, for calculations/visualizations the  actual values without rounding are used. I updated the `cut()` command in my answer so that it uses the values 25 to 48 for the bin labels. This will make sure that the x-axis is in the range you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you Till. I was able to rearrange and add a couple pieces of code to do the final plotting part.